# Able to Plot real time serial data using Matplotlib but want to make the plotting to be done at SPECIFIC FREQUENCY. (eg. min 10 Hz or max 1000 Hz)

Tags: python, multithreading, matplotlib, queue, pyserial

I'm able to plot the serial data in real time. But the problem is, its taking longer.**

(A) I am able to populate the QUEUE from incoming serial data at 10 Hz (i.e 40 data points in 4 secs) in a PRODUCER THREAD.

(B) But, at the same time I am using the populated Queue in separate CONSUMER THREAD for live plotting using matplotlib and its taking totoal 8 secs to finish the plotting of 40 data points in real time.

So, For 40 data points, its taking around 8 secs to plot in real time.

But I want it at 10 Hz, that means 40 data points to be plotted in 4 secs.

I have provided my code snippet here. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
fig = plt.figure()
plt.gcf().text(0.85, 0.91, samplingRate, fontsize=14, color='r')
fig.suptitle('Plotting at 10 Hertz.', fontsize=20, color='r')
axes =  fig.add_subplot(221)
axes.set_title('Plotting Attribute X', color='b')
axes.set_xlabel("Number of Samples")
axes.set_ylabel("Attribute X")
axes.grid(color='b', alpha=0.5, linestyle='dashed', linewidth=0.5)

xdata = []
ydata = []

axes.set_xlim(0, 130)
axes.set_ylim(-2, 2)
line, =  axes.plot( xdata,  ydata, 'r-')
counterFlag =0
while True :
    xdata.append(counterFlag)
    ydata.append(q1.get())        

    line.set_xdata( xdata)
    line.set_ydata( ydata)
    axes.relim()
    axes.autoscale()

    plt.pause(1e-50)
    counterFlag +=1
```

NOTE : Imagine q1 (line 17) declared above is the Queue that is getting serial data from the Producer thread and later getting consumed above in consumer THREAD for live plotting in matplotlib .

Comment: Did you try using the [Matplotlib Animation module](https://matplotlib.org/api/animation_api.html) ? Do you know where your bottleneck is?

Comment: The while loop would update the plot as fast as it can. At least when not having many points to draw, draw time is much shorter than 0.1 seconds. Hence the problem you observe must be with the queue. However, you do not provide a [mcve] of the issue and the queue is kept secret from the reader of the question. This question is hence pretty useless. Or, you may decide to provide a [mcve] after all.